# If cell contain any text call macro else call macro2

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

I am making a "Field Invoice" system using Excel that I almost have completely done, just doing some finishing touches.

I have a macro to export sheets as PDF depending on what was done. But I am stuck. I have two sheets "TICKET" and "TICKET2".  What I need to do is use VBA to determine if "TICKET2" is used, then it exports "TICKET" and "TICKET2" (along with some other sheets) to PDF. If "TICKET2" is not used then it only exports "TICKET" (along with other sheets).

Currently if TICKET2 has an entry, a cell on TICKET (S49) returns "Continue to Page 2":

```
=IF(TICKET2!C11>0,"Continue to Page 2","")
```

Then I am trying to use that cell to call a one of 2 macros via IF/THEN

```
Sub Export()
Dim page2 As String
page2 = Worksheets("TICKET").Range("S49")
If page2 = "Continue to Page 2" Then Call Save2page Else
    Call Save1page
End If
End Sub
```

So this is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the issue

```
page2 = Worksheets("TICKET").Range("S49")
```

It returns a Range, which is not a string.

You need to access the value of the cell instead

```
page2 = Worksheets("TICKET").Range("S49").Value
```

Answer (score -1):

What I always tell, is to simplify somethings like

```
=IF(TICKET2!C11>0,1,0)
```

If you do this is more easy to not make mistakes like case sensitive or double spaces.

But after this the rest is pretty straight foward.

```
Sub Export()
 Dim page2 As Integer
 page2 = Sheets("TICKET").Range("S49").Value
 If page2 = 1 Then 
    Call Save2page 
    Else
    Call Save1page
 End If
End Sub
```